# format exceptions was unhandled in int.parse

Tags: c#, formatexception

I'm getting this exception

> FormatException was unhandled, input string was not in a correct format.

at the following statement

```
int amnt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

what should I do to solve it?

Comment: what input are you typing in?  If you don't control the input, this where you should have a try/catch (or use int.TryParse)

Comment: its not taking any input, program stops at execution of this statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
int parsedInt = 0;

if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out parsedInt))
{
    //do success work
}
else
{
    //do failed work
}
```